# How would I compare UIButton backgroundImage title?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage, compare

On a UIButton I set background images like this

```
[twitterButton setBackgroundImage:twitterImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

twitterImage is of type UIImage

Now somewhere in the code on any button clicked I set twitterButton image using tag value

```
[twitterButton setBackgroundImage:twitterImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

My problem is How would I compare the image of twitterButton ?

this condition is not working `if([twitterbutton.imageView.image isEqual:twitterImage1])`

Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try comparing against the UIImage returned by the backgroundImageForState: method instead of the UIButton imageView's image property...

```
if ([[twitterButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:twitterImage1])
```

ie.,

```
if ([[twitterButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed@"myImage.png"]]){
  // Button has a background image named 'myImage.png'
}else{
  // Button has not a background image named 'myImage.png'
}
```

See the [UIButton class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/currentBackgroundImage) for more information.

Comment: Just tried this  if([[twitterBtn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]isEqual:twitterImage1]) ..... not working :(

Comment: How many instances of the physical image are you loading?  If it's the same object instance being set in multiple places then this should work.  Otherwise you'll have to compare the image data...

Comment: Using tag I have created a single instance. All property are working like I can change images... disable... enable... but only background image comparison is not working

Comment: If it's the same instance you could try [twitterButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == twitterImage1, although I would think that default isEqual implementation would do a pointer comparison.  Worth a shot.

Comment: Due to urgent requirement I have fixed this issue by flag. Now comparing bool flag instead of image :)

Answer (score 2):

you can't compare backgroundImage of UIButton's.you set the backgroundImage using some reference variable

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `currentBackgroundImage` property of UIButton. This will give you the current background image.. [UIButton Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Comment: I have tried this   if([twitterBtn.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:@"btn_twitter_normal_small1.png"]) 
Its not working..  is there any other way to use currentBackgroundImage property ?

Comment: Remember it returns an UIImage so you have to check that and not the image name. If that also doesn't work try isEqualTo:

Comment: you can try [twitterBtn.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:twitterImage1]

Comment: my god where i am stuck badly.... well UIImage not respond to 'isEqualTo:' ... and tried second option comparison as per your suggestion with UIImage type not with btn_twitter_normal_small1.png ... its still not working :(

Comment: oh this should have worked... Can you check if you are able to access the backgroundImage. Check if get that properly.

Comment: Due to urgent requirement I have fixed this issue by flag. Now comparing bool flag instead of image :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is expensive but you can try converting the images into nsdata and then use the isEqualToData.

Edit

```
NSData *data1=UIImagePNGRepresentation([twitterButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
NSData *data2=UIImagePNGRepresentation(anotherUIImage);

if([data1 isEqualToData:data2]){

}
```

Comment: how would i compare NSData.. i knw the condition would be like this.. if(UIIMagePng......) ..... but in this condition how would i load background button Image ?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply...Due to urgent requirement I have fixed this issue by flag. Now comparing bool flag instead of image :)

Comment: I know the feeling when you are under pressure :)

Comment: Thanks Jorge... but would like to fix this issue later... as soon as i will be free :)